# Page empty upon refresh - Passing params through router link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

So I have a router link where I pass a bunch of parameters that I want to access on the new page, and it all works well initially until I refresh the page, where all the fields are empty. Here is my ViewEvents.vue

```
<tr v-for="event in filteredEvents" v-bind:key="event">
    <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'Event', params: { eventdetails: event.eventname, name: event.eventname, venue: event.venue, date: event.date, time: event.time} }">{{event.eventname}}</router-link></td>
</tr>
```

This is how I'm accessing the details on the new page

```
data () {
  return {
    name: this.$route.params.name,
    venue: this.$route.params.venue,
    date: this.$route.params.date,
    time: this.$route.params.time,
    desc: this.$route.params.desc
  }
}
```

And this is what I have in my index.js

```
{
  path: '/events/viewevents/:eventdetails',
  name: 'Event',
  props: true,
  component: () => import('../views/events/EventDetails.vue')
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!